# Does a circle have area, and does the cube have a volume?

Tags: geometry, volume, area

A circle is just the line which is apart from the centre by a constant value so does a line have area?

And my second question is does a cube occupy a volume?

Comment: Technically a circle together with its interior should be called a disk, but it is common usage to call it a circle.

Comment: @WillJagy It's just my way of expressing my question but I'm not surely asking a trivial question, if you can rephrase the question please do

Answer (score 6):

You need to distinguish between the **perimeter** of the circle, which is a curve without area (one can also consider it to have area $0$), and the **disc** enclosed by the circle, which has area $\pi r^2$.

In everyday language, the word "circle" is used for *both* of these concepts, and one can usually guess from context which of them is meant.

In careful mathematical language, "circle" *usually* tends to mean only the perimeter curve, and the disc is called a disc, **but** there are some traditional exceptions where even mathematicians say "circle" about the disc. In particular, speaking about the area of geometrical figures ("area of the circle", "squaring the circle", etc) is such a common exception.

---

For **cubes** not even mathematics has a well-established convention that provides different words for the solid and its surface. Both are called "cube", and it is up to the speaker to provide enough context to make it clear whether he means the polyhedral surface or also its interior.

Comment: What about the cube, does it have volume?

Comment: I think it's more convenient to think about a cube as a shape not an abject

Comment: @AhmedElsawy As per Henning's answer, what do you mean by "cube?" (And what do you mean "a shape not an [o]bject"?)

Comment: @NoahSchweber I thought that people in the past might not have thought about geometric space and they called a cube according to its overall shape so it's not important if you refer to it as a non hollow object or a hollow one because a cube just refers to fixed way of organizing its parts, I was asking about opinions about that but in a brief comment

Comment: I think "hollow" vs. "not hollow" is *extremely* important to the "overall shape", and certainly to your specific question (also, what does "a fixed way of organizing its parts" mean?). Which meaning of "cube" are you asking about? Or are you asking how "cube" is used in mathematics? Or what? Please ask the precise question you want to ask.

Comment: I'm just trying to convince myself to accept this answer so I tried to make some "new"  definition of a cube but anyway, I'm asking about **Why there's no definition for a cube whether it's hollow or not!!?**

Comment: @AhmedElsawy Purely convention. Technical terms are introduced as needed. All the variants on the circle - the circle without interior ("circle"), the circle with interior ("disc"), and just the interior of the circle ("open disc") - are incredibly useful, and come up all the time in math, so it became important to have consistent names for them. The cube, for whatever reason, not so much.